# using localStorage creating weird behaviour

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a dialog page that's saving the address and port of a server in localStorage:

```
localStorage.SERVER['address'] = address;
localStorage.SERVER['port'] = port;
```

I've cut my subsequent request down to just console logging the data in localStorage to check things are working.

```
$("#login_submit").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(localStorage.SERVER['address'] + ' ' + localStorage.SERVER['port']);
}
```

What's happening though is that this executes fine when I submit the form without anything in localStorage (I get 'undefined undefined'). However after i've saved some values in the localStorage SERVER object the form reverts to behaving as normal and tries to open

```
http://mydomain/?username=&password=
```

and doesn't log anything to the console.

Comment: You need to hook into `getItem` and `setItem`, its not an associative array itself

Comment: I did some experimenting with getItem and setItem and get the behaviour that when the page is first refreshed it correctly finds the local storage, if I open the dialog and change the values it no longer recognises them and reverts to trying to use the forms normal behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this **`jsFiddle`** example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/J9NTr/, I made it for my other **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**, or it can be found **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**.

Basically **`localStorage`** data can be added/modified at any time.

Try to access them like this, this example works on desktop browsers, android and **`iOS`** devices.

```
localStorage.firstname="Dragan";
localStorage.lastname="Gaic";
```

Comment: I would avoid dot notation because it's NOT available on Windows Phone 7.